# Competitive Equilibrium how to determine subject to functions

Tags: mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, markets, competitive-equilibrium

Consider a 1-commodity, 2-consumers, 2-periods economy with
S = 2, J = 1. The asset pays one unit (of the commodity) in state 1 and 2
units in state 2. q denotes the price of the asset at time 0. The preferences of
both individuals are described by the utility function
$$ u(x0,x1,x2) = x0 · x1 +x2.$$
The initial endowments are given by
$$ ω1 = (4,0,1); $$
$$ ω2 = (1,1,1). $$
Determine a competitive equilibrium and discuss its efficiency properties.

Solution: Individual 1:
$$ max. $$ $$ x10,x11,x12,θ1 $$
$$ subject $$ $$ to $$
$$qθ^1 = 4 - x0^1$$
$$ x1^1 =  θ $$
$$ x2^1 =  1 + 2 θ $$

How do you determine the subject to q0^1 = 4-x0 , x1^1 = 0, x2^1 = 1 +20 , I don't understand how you get these functions, that is my question

Answer (score 1):

The endowment for individual 1 is $(4,0,1)$.

The price for the asset is $q$ and assume individual 1 buys $\theta$ units of the asset at period 0.

Then the total amount of money left in period 0 is:
$$
x_1 = 4 - q \theta.
$$
The 4 is the initial amount of money in period 0 and and the $- q \theta$ is the amount spend to buy the additional amount of assets.

The payout in state 1 is given by:
$$
x_1 = 0 + \theta
$$
There is an endowment of 0 but the individual bought $\theta$ assets that pay out 1 unit in state 1.

The payout in state 2 is given by:
$$
x_2 = 1 + 2 \theta.
$$
There is an endowment of 1 unit for the state 2 payout, and the asset contributes 2 euro per unit.

(remark: your optimization problem is missing an objective function).